# How get all videos from a playlist using youtube api?

Tags: php, xml, youtube, youtube-api

Now i am using this link

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/plalistID
```

to retrieve video from YouTube playlist. but the problem is only getting 25 video. but the playlist contains 100 videos. How get all video from playlist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Youtube let's you fetch up to 50 entries per request.
The response contains some `<link>` elements. And if there are still more records to fetch one of it is of the form `<link rel='next' ...` e.g.

```
<link
  rel='next'
  type='application/atom+xml'
  href='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/plalistID?start-index=26&amp;max-results=25&amp;v=2'
/>
```

Search for this element and retrieve the document that the href attribute points to until the repsonse has no `<link rel='next'` element.

Comment: Error says **No longer available**.

Answer (score 16):

**YouTube API v3**

You need to request the [**PlaylistItems > list**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) feed:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=PLVfin74Qx3tV8bgAhzbfDpnfPoGmJWAcn&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

The JSON returned by the API will contain these properties:

- `nextPageToken`
- `prevPageToken`

Pass one of these values in the `pageToken` query string parameter to retrieve the next or previous "page" in the result set:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=25&playlistId=PLVfin74Qx3tV8bgAhzbfDpnfPoGmJWAcn&pageToken=xxYYzz&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

The JSON also contains `pageInfo.resultsPerPage` and `pageInfo.totalResults` properties.

---

<sup>YouTube API v2 answer [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13407091/2).</sup>

Comment: As of 6/4/15, this type of URL just produces the phrase "No longer available" instead of the video data I used to get. Is everyone experiencing this problem? My guess is that YouTube finally removed this old API endpoint, which would be a bummer.

Comment: YouTube API v2 is deprecated. API v3 uses a different mechanism. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update Salman!
For others' reference, you can get an API key by creating an app here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started