# Get VIDEO URL for all the videos in a youtube channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am attempting to get all the videos urls or ids of a particular youtube channel.The youtube data API is not supporting it anymore .
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#invideoPromotion
Referred to this link and came to know that it is depracated.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If youtube changed its API due to ppl scaping all videos from it we won't be able to help you. We can not fix the API.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358290/how-get-all-videos-from-a-playlist-using-youtube-api
This gives videos by playlist id.It is not necessary that all videos are added under any playlist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953499/youtube-api-to-fetch-all-videos-on-a-channel) - this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44533336/7505395) on it is for python

Comment: If boths duplicates do not fit your need - distinguish your question from those duplicates. Add a [mcve] , read [ask], use the [tour] and show what you did and what exactly does not work. We can not fix youtube - we can only help with your code.

Comment: I am not sure i understand the queston.  If you want a list of all the videos in a channel why not just use videos.search what does invideopromotion have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to get property 'contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads' from channel's json object, it contains ID of playlist with all channel's videos: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads

Then next you have to call method 'playlistItems().list(your_options).execute()' with  uploads ID and any other options you want: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

In example, here we get ID of playlist with all uploaded videos:

```
channel = YOUR_YOUTUBE_KEY.channels().list(id=your_channel_id, part="contentOwnerDetails", maxResults=1).execute()
uploadsID = channel[0]["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"]
```

And list of 50 uploaded video's:

```
videosList = YOUR_YOUTUBE_KEY.playlistItems().list(part='snippet', playlistId=uploadsID, maxResults=50).execute()
```

Keep in mind the fact that maximal value of maxResults option is 50, so you have to build cycle and get next page token from videosList["nextPageToken"] to send next request with "pageToken" option that will allow you to get next 50 videos (cycle must be stopped when videosList["nextPageToken"] == "")